# Get size of ArrayList<DMatch> in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, size

I'm working in Android and I need to use the parameters goodMatches size for further processing:

```
ArrayList<DMatch> goodMatches=new ArrayList<DMatch>();
```

In C++ I've done it like this:

```
std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;
/*....
i=(int)good_matches.size();
```

But I don't know the proper way to do this in Android. Please help me find a solution.

Comment: The answer is already below, but wanted to let you know that it is Java you're using for Android programming so when searching the web for things like this you'll get a lot more luck searching "Java arraylist size" etc. Android isn't the language :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method name ist almost the same :)

```
List<DMatch> goodMatches=new ArrayList<DMatch>();
```

call the [List#size()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size()) method, this will return as integer the size of the List...

## Example:

```
int size = goodMatches.size();
```